# PreferenceFragment getActivity().finish() not working (PreferenceActivity)

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferences, preferenceactivity, preferencefragment

I want to dismiss the `PreferenceActivity` from a `PreferenceFragment`.

Calling `getActivity().finish()` from the `PreferenceFragment` just go into the Main page that contains the preference headers ( just like tapping the 
 back button).

Witch is the correct way to dismiss the `PreferenceActivity` from a `PreferenceFragment` directly?